# Excel: Adjacent Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

How do I use the IF command, or another in adjacent cells? Example, if `A1 = 'knife'` and the adjacent cell (A2) is equal to 'fork'. That is, I need to identify an adjacent cell in the vertical direction.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `AND()` function:

`IF(AND(A1="knife";A2="fork");"ok";"")`

Comment: But if cell is example, A4 and A5?

Comment: you can drag this formula down in column B and have this check on every combination of 2 adjecent cells in column A.